# How do I start a program from VB.Net and pass it arguments?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is possible? I plan to backup mysql database using vb.net. If you know any beginner tutorial on how to do this, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to start `mysql.exe` from VB.Net and supply some command-line parameters to tell it what to do (in your case, do a database backup). (FWIW, you might be better off using [`mysqldump.exe`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for that.)

You can start any process via the [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method. You'll probably want either [this variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) that gives you full control over the startup, or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) that just lets you specify the process (EXE) name and arguments. Here's a page with [lots of examples](http://dotnetperls.com/process-start-net).  They're in C#, but it shows using these methods; the syntactic differences don't (I suspect) get in the way much.

Off-the-cuff example:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Process.Start("mysqldump.exe", "myDatabaseName")
' Or include the path:
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\bin\mysqldump.exe", "myDatabaseName")
```